# Как отследить клик?

Tags: jquery, javascript

если ли в jquery как отследить клик? то есть например, при потере фокуса, я скрываю див, если при потере был клик на этом диве, его показывать. спасибо
пробовала через флаг , но все печально

```
$('.autocomplete').focusout(function(){                 
        var flag = 0;    
        $('.block_autocomplete li:not(.free_otdel)').click(function(){              
            if (flag == 0) {
                alert("1s");
                flag=1;

            } else { 
                $(this).next('.block_autocomplete').hide();
            }

        });
```

Comment: Два события не могут произойти одновременно: одно из них обязательно будет раньшше. Попробуйте "в замедленной съемке" представить себе, что происходит у вас: когда теряется фокус, когда происходит клик. Что следует за чем?

Comment: в этом примере, вы на каждый focusout вешаете слушатель click на этот li

Comment: вам может помочь вот такая развязка http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/cUkXL/